# How to plot a continuous rectangle with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame like this:

```
Start   End   Color
1        2     Blue
3        4     Red
5        6     Grey
7        8     Blue
9       10     Red
11      12     Grey
```

I want to create a rectangle along X-axis.
For every row in dataframe, I want to start the rectangle at the **Start** column and end at the **End** column with the color that is mentioned in the color column.

Here is an example image of how my rectangle should look like:

[image: Click here for demo image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Rectangle` from Matplotlib for each row in your dataframe and plot them together to make one, continuous rectangle.

Here is how you could do it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
                   'End': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                   'Color': ['Blue', 'Red', 'Grey', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Grey']})

# Initiate figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots()

for row in df.index:
    # Get x axis value where the Rectangle will start
    x_start = df['Start'][row]
    # How long the rectangle will be
    x_width = abs(df['End'][row] - x_start) + 1
    # Note: the +1 is so that the rectangles are continuous, if not, there is a gap in between them due to the
    # 'Start' and 'End' values not overlapping
    # Color of rectangle
    color_rect = df['Color'][row]
    # Make the rectangle
    rect = Rectangle(xy=(x_start, 1),
                         width=x_width,
                         height=0.5,
                         color=color_rect)

    # Add Rectangle to the figure
    axs.add_patch(rect)

axs.set_xlim([0, 15])
axs.set_ylim([0, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more info, check out the [Matplotlib Rectangle Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) - they have more examples you might find useful.